# On GCP, how can load balancing be configured to deliver the user source IP to the back end?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

On Google Cloud Platform, how can load balancing be configured to deliver the user source IP to the back end?

Comment: I walk on the fourth and seventh floors

Comment: Did you have a look to the request header? do you have a `x-forwarded-for` key-value?

Answer (score 0):

A backend service defines how Cloud Load Balancing distributes traffic.You can configure a backend service for the following Google Cloud load balancing services:

External HTTP(S) Load Balancing
Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing
SSL Proxy Load Balancing
TCP Proxy Load Balancing
Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing
External TCP/UDP Network Load Balancing
The product that you are using, which is either a load balancer or Traffic Director, determines the following:
Maximum number of backend services
Scope of a backend service
Type of backends that each backend service can use
Backend service's load balancing scheme
To configure the load balancing on GCP , please follow the instructions mentioned in the below mentioned links[1][2][3]

[ 1 ] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service

[ 2 ] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https

[ 3] https://medium.com/google-cloud/choosing-the-right-load-balancer-9ec909148a85